# UDP packet lost

Tags: networking, udp

Two servers communicate via UDP. When a large packet is send, it is not received at the other end.

I added the following registry entries

[image]

But this has not solved the problem. Below is the wireshark info regarding the lost packet. The size of the lost packet is 2706

[image]

How can I make sure that the packets are fragmented. Should I enable or disable Fragmetnation. I was not able to find a registry entry for MTU for UDP.

Comment: Many routers are configured to discard fragmented packets to prevent a fragmentation attack. Ideally, you use small packet sizes (usually no larger than about 576 bytes) with UDP because packets _will_ be lost, and smaller packets mean smaller data loss.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Is there any possibility that i could make sure that the configuration is set so? I am on a cloud environment. Unlike the other machines,  I am unable to see the properties to increase the MTU for the network on this machine.

Comment: "_I am unable to see the properties to increase the MTU for the network on this machine._ Trying to do that really doesn't make sense because the MTU is a property of the layer-1/2 protocol, and it cannot normally be increased by a setting. Most layer-1/2 protocols simply have an MTU that possibly can be decreased on an interface, but you cannot increase the default MTU for the protocol because that is limited by the hardware and/or protocol standard. The idea is that you simply do not send large UDP datagrams that will create a network packet size larger than the data-link MTU.

Comment: By the way, UDP does not use windowing. UDP is an unreliable, fire-and-forget, best-effort, connectionless, protocol that simply does not care about lost packets. If you want a reliable protocol that guarantees data delivery, then you need to use TCP, or you need to build the reliability into the application-layer protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately, using TCP is out of question at the moment. Some of the protocols installed on the machine uses UDP. With another service we make sure that the packets are transferred. The first handshake and login is successful. as soon as a bigger packet is transferred the connection is lost.

Comment: "_the connection is lost._" A connection never existed because UDP is connectionless; it doesn't make or use connections. TCP creates connections, not UDP. You must simply break the data into smaller datagrams for UDP. Understand that packets are lost all the time. TCP will notice missing segments and request the missing segments be resent, but UDP has no facility for that, so any reliability must be built into the application-layer protocol.